# Solving a non linear first order differential equation of a matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So today I stumble on a problem with a differential equation and I've looked online without finding any nice solution, here is the equation :

$$ \frac{d\hat{a}}{dt} = \alpha \hat{a} + \beta \hat{a}^2 $$

Comment: Well as scalar this is just separable ode $\frac{d\hat{a}}{dt} = \alpha \hat{a} + \beta \hat{a}^2$  isn't $\hat{a}(t)$ the dependent variable and everything else are just parameters?

Comment: With $a(t) \in \mathbb{R}$, the solution is : a(t) = $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha C e^{-\alpha t}-\beta} $ With $C$ a integration constant

Comment: yes, that is correct. as scalar, it is just integration. nothing else.

Comment: Yeah but my problem is that $\hat{a}$ is an operator, that is to say an "infinite" 2 dimentional matrice, and I think that, to be able to use this solution $\hat{a}$ should be inversible, and it is not